# Access service api exposed as clusterIP in kubernete

Tags: c#, docker, kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

I have two application, both deployed in same cluster.

Now from web, there is an ajax request to get data from api, but it always return `502 Connection refused`.

here is my jquery code (web).

```
$.get("http://10.43.244.118/api/users", function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        $('#table').bootstrapTable({
            data: data
        });
    });
```

Note: when I change the service type to `LoadBalancer` from `ClusterIP` then it works fine.

Comment: [service type behaviours](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#publishing-services-service-types) covers this. As LoadBalancer it will expose the service using the cloud providers load balancer. ClusterIP is an internal ip and would not be visible to the other docker container

Answer (score 1):

ClusterIP services (usually) only work within the cluster. You can technically make your CNI address space available externally, but that is rare and you probably shouldn't count on it. The correct way to expose something outside the cluster is either a NodePort service or a LoadBalancer (which is a NodePort plus a cloud load balancer).

Comment: But my both web and api are in same cluster, so it should work

Comment: The web browser is not in the cluster, and that looks like fromtend code?

Comment: yes, But this code is written in application, that application is in same cluster.

Comment: Yes but it actually runs in your web browser on your workstation. Where the application is doesn’t matter.

Comment: Now I have changed service tyoe to NodePort, but it is still not accessible.

Comment: You have to find the randomly generated port number from the service object and then access any cluster node on that port.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/194111/discussion-between-programmer-and-coderanger).

Answer (score 0):

```
1\Ajax is a front-end call to api.
2\The front-end call is to directly communicate with the user(Browser) and the called end and the api service.
3\ ClusterIP is internal to the cluster,User(Browser) cannot communicate with it.
4\ NodePort and LoadBalancer can expose the internal network, of course, it can be accessed normally.
```